# How to open column below another column in minimum screen resolution of a RWD layout structure through CSS Media Query code?

Tags: css, media-queries

In this below CSS structure, the RIGHTCOLUMN, CONTENT, LEFTCOLUMN needs to open in the same order one by one. That is the properties of #rightcolumn #content #leftcolumn should be visible in the same order of screen as 1,2,3 (for low width resolution devices below 600px)

As Below:

header
title -
description -
rightcolumn -
content -
leftcolumn -
footer

One gentle man Mr.Pschueller helped me with Media queries. It was useful. But its just for 2 columns, that it #content and #leftcolumn.

When i try the same for 3 columns my brain Hangs.  So i may need some one help. The code is given below. I don't know where I am wrong.

The present screen status of this code is:

header -
title -
description -
content -
rightcolumn -
leftcolumn -
footer

So the RIGHTCOLUMN should open BEFORE CONTENT without overlapping. This is my issue now.

```
body {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        color:#333
}

p {
        padding: 10px;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: auto;
    max-width: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
        float: left;
    height: 80px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #3b5998;
}
#title {
        float: left;
        height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #ffffff;
}
#description {
        float: left;
        height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #f2f2f2;
}

#leftcolumn {
        background: #FFFFFF;
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: -100%;
}
#rightcolumn {
        background: #FFFFFF;
        width: 340px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: -340px;
}
#content {
        background: #FFFFFF;
        margin-left: 201px;
        margin-right: 340px;
}
#contentliquid {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
}

#footer {
        height: 30px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #3B5998;
        clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        #content {
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-right: 0;
            float: none;
        }
        #rightcolumn {
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-right: 0;
            float: none;
        }
        #leftcolumn
        {
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-right: 0;
            float: none;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue myself:

The last code of the Media queries is edited as follows and it is able to work even in 240x320 Screen resolution. As i expected now I am able to open the site in blackberry phone in the order 1,2,3 which results header title - description - content - rightcolumn - leftcolumn - footer

Below is the editing I made at the end: Note: If you add flot in the last LEFTCOLUMN then the screen will start to overlap.

I am not a Designer or a Programmer. But i am doing this for time pass by learning simple things. So those who are professionals don't joke with my addings.

On the browsing way i came to this stackoverflow and finally my problem is solved.

Thanking you.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) 
{
    #content {
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        float: none;

    }
    #rightcolumn {
        margin-left: 0;
        float: none;
    }
    #leftcolumn
        {
        margin-left: 0;


    }
}
```